# Upgrade failed- forbidden downloading

Tags: apt

I use proxy to connect to the Internet. I am trying to upgrade to 12.10. The problem is that some(nearly all) packages are downloaded but some 3 Mb data is not downloading, due to which the upgradation aborts reporting a forbidden error. These are some files related to gnome-games and facebook integration. Facebook is blocked on the proxy server which i am using, so i guess the error appears due to that. I want to ask if there is any way i can skip downloading the last 3 Mb packages(which i don't need) so that my upgradation continues to Ubuntu 12.10?
This is the error i am getting:

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-games/gnomine_3.6.0.2-0ubuntu1.2_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-games/mahjongg_3.6.0.2-0ubuntu1.2_all.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-games/gnome-mahjongg_3.6.0.2-0ubuntu1.2_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-games/gnome-sudoku_3.6.0.2-0ubuntu1.2_all.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gnome-games/gnome-games-data_3.6.0.2-0ubuntu1.2_all.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/account-plugins/account-plugin-facebook_0.8-0ubuntu2_i386.deb 403  Forbidden
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gwibber/gwibber-service-facebook_3.6.0-0ubuntu1.1_all.deb 403  Forbidden
```

Comment: Put the exact error text here.  Without it we can't help figure out how to fix this.

Comment: I have updated the post with the exact error

Comment: Have you tried using a different archive mirror, perhaps one of the regional ones?  (403s happen sometimes)

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Go to System Settings--> Software Resources--> Ubuntu Software Tab, and change Download server.

Comment: What Mitch said.  If that works, then I'll create an answer from me and Mitch's comments, giving them ample attribution for the solutions.

Comment: Don't worry about the proxy - the error messages indicate a reply from the mirror.

Comment: I think that the most likely cause its your proxy, the words *games* and *facebook* makes me extremally suspicious.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to upgrade/install those packages, is actually very easy. If you don't use them just uninstall them:

```
sudo apt-get remove <packages to remove>
```

To prevent that they try to get installed/upgraded you could put them on hold:

```
echo <package> hold | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```